# TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to import a variable from a file through a variable and then trying to compare the value to an input.
But when running my script I am running into the following error:

`TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable`

This is the list from the file I try to import:
`var1 = ['cookies','pretzels']`

This is my code:

```
usri = input('what is your favorite pastry')
#compare count is a counter with for example the value 1. The counter then joins the var. 
#My idea is that var1 will be the variable which is being imported.
allowlist = str('var{}'.format(compare_count))
#Now I am trying to import var1 from my_file
allowlist = __import__('my_file'.format(allowlist))   

#after var1 is imported from my_file I want to check if the user input is an item of var1
if usri in allowlist:
    print('user input was found')
else:
   print('user input wasn't found')

#In this example var1 is the only variable in the file I try to import but in the main code there are a lot of other variables.
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? If so I would be really glad if someone could tell me what I've made wrong and help me solve this problem:)

Thank's for every help and suggestion in advance:)

Comment: ``__import__`` is a very low-level function and will return the *root* of what was imported, not the *leave*. ``importlib`` has a more ergonomic, high-level interface. Either way it looks as if you should be using a proper data format, such as csv, JSON, or similar, instead of abusing ``import`` to load things that are not modules.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate how to use import. Create a python file to import from, like `my_file.py`:

```
allowlist = ["a", "b", "c]
```

Then you can import it like this in your other code:

```
from my_file import allowlist

print(allowlist)
```

Then allowlist will be the list `["a", "b", "c"]` and you can use it as a list.